# Zoom to the most vertically middle line

Tags: jquery, css

I got a div containing children and each child holds a line of text.

```
<div id="aboutxt">
    <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
    <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
    <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
    <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
    <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
    <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to zoom into the line i.e. at the (vertically) middle of the page. Also the divs next to it should be zoomed in but not as much as the focused one.
Assume, the 10th line is at the middle of the page right now. So, the zooms should be:

```
Line 1: zoom 1
Line 2: zoom 1
Line 3: zoom 1
Line 4: zoom 1
Line 5: zoom 1.1
Line 6: zoom 1.2
Line 7: zoom 1.3
Line 8: zoom 1.4
Line 9: zoom 1.5
Line 10: zoom 2
Line 11: zoom 1.5
Line 12: zoom 1.4
Line 13: zoom 1.3
Line 14: zoom 1.2
Line 15: zoom 1.1
Line 16: zoom 1
Line 17: zoom 1
Line 18: zoom 1
```

As you see 5 previous and 5 next neighbors have been zoomed in and the challenging part is, I need it behaving on scroll. So, when the parent is being scrolled down/up, zooms change depending to which line is focused. You may have seen this effect before. But I've no idea what it's called.
Hope I've explained my meaning good.

Comment: Please show your code. Also, I can see that you've never accepted an answer on any of your questions. Please go back through them and see which answers should be marked.

Comment: If you mean jQuery codes, I've nothing now. I tried several ways but none of them worked. So, I'm at the beginning again. About the answers, OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is what you are looking for

```js
$('.line').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    'zoom': 1.2
  }, 100).css({
    'color': '#f00'
  });
  $(this).prev().animate({
    'zoom': 1.1
  }, 100).css({
    'color': '#000'
  });
  $(this).prev().prev().animate({
    'zoom': 1.0
  }, 100);
  $(this).next().animate({
    'zoom': 1.1
  }, 100).css({
    'color': '#000'
  });
  $(this).next().next().animate({
    'zoom': 1.0
  }, 100).css({
    'color': '#000'
  });
});
$('#aboutxt').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.line').animate({
    'zoom': 1.0
  }, 100).css({
    'color': '#000'
  });
});
```

```css
#aboutxt {
  text-align: center;
}
#aboutxt .line {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aboutxt">
  <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
  <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
  <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
  <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
  <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
  <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
  <div class="line">A_LINE_OF_THE_WHOLE_TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it to work on scroll and with offset detection not mouse over.

Comment: maybe if you are looking something similar to a selector plugin, check there links [Drum JS](https://mb.aquarius.uberspace.de/drumjs/examples/layout_options.html) & [Drum-style selector](http://codepen.io/coffeedawg/pen/sifcj)

Comment: I figured it out with your idea some way else. I like .next().next() idea since I've not a lot of items to work out. Thanks.